# How to transform a square to a trapezoid in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I transform a HTML Canvas from a square to a trapezoid?

For example

```
 ___ 
|   |
|___|

to
 ___
/___\
```

Comment: You want to transform the actual canvas element, or stuff inside it?

Comment: The simple answer is you can't. Canvas only supports affine transformations, which means scaling, rotation, and skewing. Perspective transforms are currently only supported in Safari. Now, since canvas allows pixel level manipulation, anything is possible really, but the solution would be very complex and likely poorly performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the raphael framework.
http://raphaeljs.com/

This should help ... although it's not an complete answer. Seems like there's going to be a lot of math going on through a stack of canvas items.

Comment: Raphael Framework seems to be with SVG graphics instead of Canvas.